# No such file or directory but directory is right there

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-12.04

I am doing some crypto testing with openssl on ubuntu 12.04 and I have a directory build with the following specs:

```
$home/   
  demoCA/
    certs
    index.txt
    serial
    openssl.cnf
    newcerts/
    crl/
```

And everytime I run a command, specifically this:

```
openssl ca -in server.csr -out server.crt -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -config openssl.cnf
```

it tells me:

> I am unable to access the ./demoCA/newcerts directory
>
> ./demoCA/newcerts: No such file or directory

There are a few commands I run before this to set it up and I'd be glad to outline them if that would be helpful but I have no idea why it won't find that one directory.  Any suggestions?

This is the lab I am running along with [this](http://www.cis.syr.edu/%7Ewedu/seed/Labs/Crypto/Crypto_PublicKey/Crypto_PublicKey.pdf).

Comment: not sure if this matters, but is it a private directory that wont let a 3rd party (openSSL) access?

Comment: no my previous commands using openssl that don't use this directory have worked without a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why no such file or directory does not exist is because you are trying to access

> demoCA

not

> democa

Linux treats file directories as unique when they have different values -especially when they are lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: ah my apologies, that was a typo on my stackoverflow question but not in my actual filesystem setup.  good eye though, I've corrected it in the question.

Comment: Bash is telling you the problem. Your script or command is trying to access something it cannot find. Go to ./demoCA/newcerts in your bash and 'pwd' that will be the exact script you use for file direction. If that doesn't work, then the file that is actually calling the command to access that directory is incorrect. There is an issue with your file path reference.

Comment: I will also add that it could be possible that your script does not have permission to access that directory. Go to where your main script is in which references the './demoCA/newcerts' dir and do an 'ls -la' and see the file permissions. Make sure that the proper files have read(r) for user, group, and other for permissions. You can change permissions via chmod.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to think about it on a more basic level and printing the working directory and then changing where it was looking in the configuration file got it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its simple just make another **directory demoCA** inside the demoCA folder and put files in the **directory demoCA**

```
$home/

demoCA/

demoCA

certs
index.txt
serial
crl
```

it will work fine....you have to put these files inside folder named demoCA otherwise it will not find it.