# I am unable to access the./demoCA/newcerts: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am trying to sign my *CSR* file with my *CA*.

I am using the following command :

```
openssl ca -in server.csr -out server.crt -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -config openssl.cnf
```

My *openssl.cnf* has not been altered and it is at its default state.

Please refer to pic below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Can you try giving access to newcerts directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No such file or directory but directory is right there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225787/no-such-file-or-directory-but-directory-is-right-there)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: czifro is correct.  The ./demoCA is specified in the openssl.cnf file

Answer (score 2):

When this command is run in the demoCA folder, and it is looking for newcerts folder, it should just search for `newcerts`, but is instead searching for `./demoCA/newcerts`, even though it is already in the newcerts folder! I don't know why...

To fix this, I moved up a folder (out of the demoCA folder, and into whatever folder is holding your demoCA folder), then changed the command so that all the files have ./demoCA in front of them:

```
openssl ca -in ./demoCA/server.csr -out ./demoCA/server.crt -cert ./demoCA/ca.crt -keyfile ./demoCA/ca.key -config ./demoCA/openssl.cnf
```

Then it finally worked for me!!

(A better way to fix the issue would be to figure out why it is searching for `./demoCA/newcerts` instead of simply newcerts, but I couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: Default directory in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf is demoCA

Answer (score 1):

Modifying permissions is an easy test to see if you are targeting the wrong location. For kicks and grins try your overriding the out location to the same location you are working with, like this:

```
openssl ca -in server.csr -out ~/demoCA/server.crt -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -config openssl.cnf
```

Comment: The `#` in this instance is not part of the dir name. It is Linux's way of indicating root session. If you do `sudo su` in a Linux terminal, you will notice the `$` change to a `#`.

Comment: Not the best idea to run around as root...either way giving openssl a set location for an out file which is known to be accessible should resolve the problem.